# Нет прав для доступа к серверу при одном и том же владельце папки и процесса Apache. Как устранить?

Tags: linux, apache

Расклад следующий. Удаленный VDS-сервер, ставлю LAMP.

Указываю в файле **/etc/apache/envvars**

```
APACHE_RUN_USER = musaevhs
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = musaevhs
```

В файле **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName musaevhs.ru
    DocumentRoot /home/musaevhs/www

    <Directory '/home/musaevhs/www/'>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow From All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Владелец папки - **musaevhs**, у этого пользователя sudo-права.
И все равно выплевывает

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at musaevhs.ru Port 80

Есть соображения, куда копать? Если выставляю **DocumentRoot** в папку **/srv**, которую создал в корне, то все работает, файлы читает. У папки **/srv** владелец **root**.

Answer (score 3):

часто применяемая для такой ситуации практика — добавлять пользователя, от имени которого выполняются «дочерние» процессы *apache* («родительский» всегда должен работать от имени *root*-а — ведь только *root* имеет право создавать сокеты на портах с номером меньше 1024), в требуемую группу.

чаще всего встречается пользователь `www-data` (зависит от того, как собран и сконфигурирован *apache*, уточнить можно, например, по первому полю в списке процессов: `ps aux | grep 'USER\|apache\|httpd`).

в вашем случае добавить его в группу `musaevhs` можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G musaevhs www-data
```

после этого надо перезапустить *apache* (именно перезапустить: сделать не *reload*, а *restart*).

---

естественно, и каталог `/home/musaevhs`, и каталог `/home/musaevhs/www`, и подкаталоги последнего должны принадлежать группе `musaevhs` и  быть читабельны для группы. можно в этом убедиться с помощью команды `ls -ld /путь/к/каталогу`, а можно сразу и исправить, не уточняя, например, так:

```
$ sudo chown :musaevhs /home/musaevhs
$ sudo chmod g+rx /home/musaevhs
$ sudo chown -R :musaevhs /home/musaevhs/www
$ sudo find /home/musaevhs/www -type d -exec chmod g+rx {} +
```