# Ошибка при клонировании git репозитория по http

Tags: ubuntu, git, http, access

Сервер с `ubuntu 14.04` На сервере установлено:

```
git
gitolite
apache2
```

На сервер попадаю по адресу `http://git.test/`

Репозитории на сервере находятся по пути `/home/git/repositories`

В `/home/git/repositories` есть пустой репозиторий `test`

Создал новую конфигурацию для виртуального хоста:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.com.conf


<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/git/repositories
ServerName gitserver

<Directory "/home/git/repositories">
Allow from All
Options +ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/git/repositories
ScriptAlias /git /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
</VirtualHost>
```

Сделал:

```
 $ sudo a2ensite git.test.conf
```

`$ sudo service apache2 restart`

На клиенте в gitBash:

```
$ git clone http://git.test/home/git/repositiries/test
```

Выпадает ошибка:

```
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://git.test/home/git/repositiries/test/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Также в браузере по адресу `http://git.test/`:

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Понимаю что проблема в правах. Но не понимаю какие и на какие файлы или папки их ставить.

Вот что в файле `/etc/group`

```
$ cat /etc/group
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog,gitroot
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:gitroot
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:gitroot
audio:x:29:
dip:x:30:gitroot
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
gnats:x:41:
shadow:x:42:
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:
sasl:x:45:
plugdev:x:46:gitroot
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:
users:x:100:
nogroup:x:65534:
libuuid:x:101:
netdev:x:102:
crontab:x:103:
syslog:x:104:
fuse:x:105:
messagebus:x:106:
mlocate:x:107:
ssh:x:108:
landscape:x:109:
gitroot:x:1000:
lpadmin:x:110:gitroot
sambashare:x:111:gitroot
git:x:1001:gitroot
ssl-cert:x:112:
```

Лог access.log

```
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:10:40:22 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3594 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:10:40:22 +0200] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3688 "http://git.test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:10:58:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:10:31 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:10:31 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 501 "http://git.test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2$
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:11:56 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:11:56 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 501 "http://git.test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2$
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:19:17 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3594 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:19:17 +0200] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3688 "http://192.168.196.133/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Ge$
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:19:17 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "http://192.168.196.133/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome$
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:22:31 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 491 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:22:31 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 501 "http://git.test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2$
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:23:56 +0200] "GET /home/git/repositiries/test/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 471 "-" "git/2.5.1.windows.1"
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:36:07 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3594 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
192.168.196.1 - - [02/Nov/2015:11:36:07 +0200] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3688 "http://192.168.196.133/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Ошибка все та же.

Виртуальных серверов больше нет кроме стандартного на который я попадаю с клиента без проблем по IP.
Ошибка все та же.

Comment: пользователю, от которого выполняются процессы apache, недоступен каталог /home/git/repositories. решение изложено, например, здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/441737/178576

Comment: *Ошибка все та же* — 1. уберите пользователей git и www-data из группы sudo! 2. в chown изпользуйте группу git. 3. включите пользователя www-data в группу git. 4. перезпустите apache.

Comment: убрать пользователя из группы в debian-основных дистрибутивах можно командой `$ sudo deluser пользователь группа`.

Comment: Ошибка не изменилась

Comment: пользователь www-data не входит в группу git. а пользователь git зачем-то включен в группу www-data. исправьте и перезапустите apache. проверить членство в группах можно командой `id пользователь`

Comment: исправил. Файл групп в вопросе. ошибка осталась

Comment: 1. команда `$ sudo -u www-data /home/git/repositories` выводит содержимое этого каталога? 2. apache перезапускали и ошибок при этом не получили? (`$ sudo service apache2 restart`). 3. в бразуере адрес `http://gitserver/` открывается нормально?

Comment: 1, команда `$ sudo -u www-data /home/git/repositories` выдает `sudo: /home/git/repositories: command not found` 2, перезагружаю именно так 3, В броузере ошибка все та же как и в вопросе

Comment: прошу прощения, `ls` пропустил. `$ sudo -u www-data ls /home/git/repositories`

Comment: Да выводит содержимое каталога

Comment: хорошо, продолжаем проверки. закомментируйте в в приведённой конфигурации четыре строки, начинающиеся с `options`, `setenv` и `scriptalias`, перезапустите apache и попробуйте открыть в браузере `http://gitserver/`.

Comment: Вылетает та же ошибка  `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Comment: ну, значит, смотрите логи apache, куда именно он при запросах пытается обратиться. вероятно, у вас ещё какие-то virtualhost-ы вмешиваются в работу.

Comment: Оказывается вся проблема была в версии apache. Все мануалы написаны под версию 2,2. А в 2,7 есть изменения в настройках доступа.